# displaying Flash message in react

Tags: reactjs, flash-message

My task is to display flash message("successfully created") on clicking the submit button.[On clicking the submit button , data will be stored in the server]I have run this command npm i react-flash-message.

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
 </form>
```

handleSubmit function:

```
  handleSubmit(event) {
     fetch('url', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                name: this.state.name,
                description: this.state.description
            })
        }).then(res => {
            return res.json()
        })
            .then(data => console.log(data))
            .then(() => {
                window.location.reload(false)
                /* return (
                     <div>
                        <FlashMessage duration={5000}>
                            <strong>I will disapper in 5 seconds!</strong>
                       </FlashMessage>
                   </div>
                 ) */
            })
            /* window.flash('record has been created successfully!', 'success') */

            .catch(error => console.log('ERROR from create component'))
      }
     }
```

I have commented the code I have tried to display flash message. But it is not working. Please someone help me to display the flash message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to react-flash-message page , you should include the FlashMessage in your render. So you may need to have a flag variable to set as true when you want to show the FlashMessage

Example:
in your render :

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
   { this.state.showMessage &&  
        <div>
            <FlashMessage duration={5000}>
                <strong>I will disappear in 5 seconds!</strong>
            </FlashMessage>
        </div>
   }
  
 </form>
```

handleSubmit function :

```
handleSubmit(event) {
 this.setState({ showMessage: false });
 fetch('url', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                name: this.state.name,
                description: this.state.description
            })
        }).then(res => {
            return res.json()
        })
            .then(data => console.log(data))
            .then(() => {
                this.setState({ showMessage: true });
            })
            /* window.flash('record has been created successfully!', 'success') */

            .catch(error => console.log('ERROR from create component'))
      }
}
```

main function if you are using class:

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showMessage: false
    };
  }
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-flash-message

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yeah, this code displays the flash message. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Easy peasy.. 
Whenever using onSubmit, dont forget to use event.preventDefault()..

And try using only one then block.

Now maintain a state variable, to set the status of the result. Once the result is fetched set the result status to true.

Render your FlashMessage component, when its true.

https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-taussig-9x0o3

Comment: Thanks for your quick response and advise. This code helped me to display the flash message.